# How to get the total number of occurences of a specific item in every document's array element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am implementing favoriting/unfavoriting functionality to my express app but I have a problem on how to count the the total number the post has been favorited.

Assuming I have this Schema for Recipe

```js
RecipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: 30
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  favoritesCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
})
```

And Schema for User

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 8,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  fullname: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 40,
    minlength: 4,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 8
  }
  favorites: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Recipe'
  }]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

And now assuming I have this doc of Users,
How can I count the total number the **Recipe ID (5daef9a2761d4b1668214dbc)** present in each User doc's favorites array?

```js
[{
  username: 'john123',
  email: 'john@test.com',
  favorites: ['5daef9a2761d4b1668214dbc']
}, {
  username: 'jane75',
  email: 'jane@test.com',
  favorites: []
}, {
  username: 'johnwick',
  email: 'johnwick@test.com',
  favorites: ['5daef9a2761d4b1668214dbc']
}]

// Should yield 2
```

I looked up for answers but I can't find one. I'm new to mongodb and nodejs so please bear with me. Some answers that I saw are related to Aggregation.

So far I have tried this code. But it just return the number of User documents.

```js
const User = require('./User') // the User model

RecipeSchema.methods.updateFavoriteCount = function() {
  return User.count({
    favorites: {
      $in: [this._id]
    }
  }).then((count) => {
    this.favoritesCount = count;
    return this.save();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of `aggregation` and with `$size`. For more detail, refer to this [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/).

**Your query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      username: 1,
      email: 1,
      totalFavritesCount: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $isArray: "$favorites"
          },
          then: {
            $size: "$favorites"
          },
          else: "NA"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "email": "john@test.com",
    "totalFavritesCount": 1,
    "username": "john123"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "email": "jane@test.com",
    "totalFavritesCount": 0,
    "username": "jane75"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "email": "johnwick@test.com",
    "totalFavritesCount": 1,
    "username": "johnwick"
  }
]
```

You can also check out the running code in this [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OOcKwueLxTm).

Comment: Please refrain from rolling back any more edits, Pushprajsinh.

Comment: Do note that vote begging here is not tolerated, and moderators will uphold any edits that attempt to revert such changes. It is much better to let people vote organically on answers - if they are good they will be upvoted naturally.

Comment: But sometimes the OP doesn't appriciate the answer .Anyways , will take care and will not ask for appriciation . Thanks for correcting me . @halfer

Comment: There is no obligation on the OP to upvote (or even reply to) an answer. That said, it is OK to add a comment to ask if your solution helped. If you suspect the OP does not know how to accept an answer (e.g. they have zero or very few accepted answers) then you can point them to the Stack Overflow documentation. But don't put this kind of thing in answers - it is definitely comment-only material.